# -ctly pronunciation in British (ex. exactly, correctly etc.)

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, elision

I have a question about the pronunciation of these words in British accent; exactly, correctly etc.
I am more familiar with the American accent, so I tend to ignore the 't' between two consonants.
Do British people also skip the 't'?

Comment: Do you have any particular dialect of British English in mind as i suspect this may vary.

Comment: It varies from speaker to speaker.

Comment: And on circumstances. I might omit the 't' when saying _exactly_ quickly, but pronounce it when saying the word with emphasis to confirm what someone had just said.

Comment: I might say it, but you might not hear it.

Comment: @mdewey Maybe RP?

Comment: I (mostly) speak RP, and I believe I always pronounce the 't' in those words.

Answer (score 2):

These are the pronunciations given in Lexico's UK dictionary.  The "t"s are shown as optional.  It is fair to say they aren't always pronounced in casual speech.

- *exactly* /ɪɡˈzak(t)li/ or /ɛɡˈzak(t)li/ ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/exactly))
- *correctly* /kəˈrɛk(t)li/ ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/correctly))

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker of British English and also an accent trainer. It is very common among native speakers to drop the /t/ in 'exactly' so that it sounds like egg-ZAK-li.

It also happens to 'correctly', but in that case it is considered sloppy to drop the /t/ and say cur-REK-li.

The reason it happens is that in a cluster of three consonants, the middle consonant, is frequently dropped in casual speech.

Similar words in which the /t/ may be dropped:
directly → die-REK-li
perfectly → per-FEK-li
distinctly → dis-TINK-li